# Gatsby Global SCSS not being applied

Tags: gatsby

My Gatsby project's styling from `global.scss` file is not being applied.

I have a global stylesheet called `global.scss` that is located in `src/styles/` and then I am also using component-scoped scss modules.

In my `gatsby-browser.tsx` file, I am importing the global file like so:

```
import './src/styles/global.css'
```

However, this does nothing. I am not getting my styles from that file applied to any of my pages. Why won't importing a global stylesheet actually work? I've tried it with plain css instead of scss to no avail...

Here is my `gatsby-browser.tsx` file

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { PrismicProvider } from '@prismicio/react'
import {
  PrismicPreviewProvider,
  componentResolverFromMap,
} from 'gatsby-plugin-prismic-previews'
import './src/styles/global.scss'
import { GatsbyBrowser, Link } from 'gatsby'
import { linkResolver } from './src/utils/linkResolver'
import IndexPage from './src/pages'
import PageTemplate from './src/pages/{prismicPage.url}'
import ArticleTemplate from './src/pages/{prismicArticle.url}'

interface Props {
  element: React.ReactNode
}

const wrapRootElement: GatsbyBrowser['wrapPageElement'] = ({
  element,
}: Props) => (
  <PrismicProvider
    internalLinkComponent={({ href, ...props }) => (
      <Link to={href} target={props.target} rel={props.rel}>
        {props.children}
      </Link>
    )}
  >
    <PrismicPreviewProvider
      repositoryConfigs={[
        {
          repositoryName: process.env.PRISMIC_REPO_NAME ?? '',
          linkResolver,
          componentResolver: componentResolverFromMap({
            homepage: IndexPage,
            page: PageTemplate,
            article: ArticleTemplate,
          }),
        },
      ]}
    >
      {element}
    </PrismicPreviewProvider>
  </PrismicProvider>
)

export default wrapRootElement
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing it in your `Layout` component? Despite your approach should work the preferred way ([according to the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/global-css/#adding-global-styles-with-a-layout-component)) is through the `Layout` component:

```
import React from "react"
import "../styles/global.scss"

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

Comment: Not specifically my Layout, but I put it into my page files and it worked. I just don't know why it's not imported with Gatsby-browser...

Comment: Have you tried changing the extension to JavaScript (`.js`)? Just to test if it has something to do about TypeScript compilation or something

Comment: Yes and something. But I don't want to use js, I want to use TS

Comment: Typescript support for Gatsby's APIs has been released in the new version. Does the JS approach works?

Comment: No it does not. It doesn't work with either extension